# How to "cd" into system files

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have files saved under `Macintosh HD/Library/...` that I need to manipulate using bash. How can I access those files in the shell?

Answer (score 4):

All mounted volumes on OS X are mounted to the "/Volumes" directory. Thus, you would enter this in the terminal:

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library
```

"\ " indicates a space.

Comment: Note that if "Macintosh HD" is your system disk then `cd /Library` should suffice because the root of the system disk is mounted at `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to upper ans. You can use single quote or double quote. This is sometimes easier to use as you dont have to escape individual space. Ex:

```
cd "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library"
cd '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library'
```

NOTE: If you are on the mac. Pressing TAB key will auto complete your dir names and it will auto escape spaces for you.